# Easiest way to go about using a method

Tags: java, swing

If I wanted to write a list of code 10 times, Would I be using a method and how should I go about it to make it easiest?

The code I need to duplicate is:

```
if (LastColor == 1) {
            GREEN.apply();
        } else if (LastColor == 2) {
            PINK.apply();
        } else if (LastColor == 3) {
            ORANGE.apply();
        } else if (LastColor == 4) {
            YELLOW.apply();
        } else if (LastColor == 5) {
            BLUE.apply();
        } else if (LastColor == 6) {
            PURPLE.apply();
        } else if (LastColor == 7) {
            BLACK.apply();
        }
```

Comment: Question a bit unclear. What do you mean by *a list of code*? Do you mean lines of code that you need to reuse frequently?

Comment: That depends a lot on what you expect this method to actually do.  If each statement is the same, then just move the code to a method and call it.  If you want to be able to change the way it works, you'll need to provide parameters...

Comment: If you have the same code on two different spots, *always* consider writing a method.

Comment: by the way, its essayer to use switch & case,

Comment: Consider using an `enum` instead of `int` values for `LastColor`.

Comment: qqilihq,exception1,java-love,griffeydog
thanks plasmaPower had answered it quite well. 

@MadProgrammer sorry it was unclear, each statement was the same so It is all fixed now.

Thankyou all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a constant array:

```
final Color[] colors = {null, GREEN, PINK, ORANGE, YELLOW, BLUE, PURPLE, BLACK};
```

Then you could just do

```
colors[LastColor].apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into a method and make LastColor a parameter for the method i.e.

```
void applyColor(int LastColor) {
....
}
```

Also you might want to replace all those `if else` clauses with a `switch case` statement. It would look alot cleaner